# Strange Facebook OpenGraph Error

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm trying to set opengraph properties for our site but facebook refuses to see them.

I managed to reduce our content to a level, where facebook can see the og meta tags. It is available under http://cancellar.hu/test.html (note: deleted 99% of content)

I can see everything in linter: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://cancellar.hu/test.html

But when I add just a few ascii characters (notice: "felhasznal") to the second p: http://cancellar.hu/test2.html

Facebook says it has no tags: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint/?url=http://cancellar.hu/test2.html

```
# diff test.html test2.html 
41c41
< </p>
---
> felhasznal</p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After long testing I wrote a filter which removes the html's body part if the user agent is a facebook bot. We had no errors since then.