# Facebook not getting opengraph tags from "large" pages. Any fix?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph, meta-tags

This is an Opengraph related question. In a simple webpage with OG implemented, Facebook doesn't get the tags from the link. other testers do.

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4227610/strange-facebook-opengraph-error), Dutow said he trimmed his page and it worked, so I did the same:

- I used 2 files, [`test1.php`](https://uno.ooo/test1.php) and [`test2.php`](https://uno.ooo/test2.php). The code of both is below.
- I tested `test1`, a very simple and small page. [It was detected as `404` by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Funo.ooo%2Ftest1.php).
- After, I tested `test2`, a trimmed version of `test1`, keeping just the OG part of the head. [It was detected by Facebook as `test1` was intended to](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/?q=https%3A%2F%2Funo.ooo%2Ftest2.php).

I read  on a blog something about the website's response time, but I lost the link.

So, kind of knowing the reason of the problem...

***QUESTIONS***

- How can a "bigger" page be detected properly by facebook?
- Else, How can a single page be served complete to users and "trimmed" for facebook?
- If the fix is by filtering by user agent, as Dutow did. How can this be done and not be detected as cheating by search engines? (an example, please)
- Any way, trick or workaround will be thanked.

***test1.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'
xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#'
prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
    <head>
        <!--Meta tags-->
        <title>UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú</title>
        <meta content='text/html' charset='utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'/>
        <!--Open graph-->
        <meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
        <meta property='og:title' content='UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú'/>
        <meta property='og:image' content='https://uno.ooo/rec/img/carita_1000x500.png'/>
        <meta property='og:image:alt' content='Previsualizacíón de la imagen de presentación.'/>
        <meta property='og:image:width' content='1000'/>
        <meta property='og:image:height' content='500'/>
        <meta property='og:description' content='UNO es una empresa emergente de TI. Queremos ayudar a que su negocio o idea sea aún mejor mediante el uso de software. También subcontratamos el desarrollo de software.  UNO is an IT startup. We want to help make your business or idea even better by using software. We also outsource software development.'/>
        <meta property='og:url' content='uno.ooo'>
        <meta property='og:site_name' content='uno.ooo'>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="es_PE">
                <!--Twitter cards-->
        <meta name='twitter:card' content='summary' />
        <meta name='twitter:title' content='UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú'>
        <meta name='twitter:description' content='UNO es una empresa emergente de TI. Queremos ayudar a que su negocio o idea sea aún mejor mediante el uso de software. También subcontratamos el desarrollo de software.  UNO is an IT startup. We want to help make your business or idea even better by using software. We also outsource software development.'>
        <meta name='twitter:image' content='https://uno.ooo/rec/img/carita_1000x500.png'>
        <meta name='twitter:site' content=''>
        <!--Pinterest-->
        <meta name='p:domain_verify' content=''/>

        <meta name='title' content='UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú' />
        <meta name='description' content='UNO es una empresa emergente de TI. Queremos ayudar a que su negocio o idea sea aún mejor mediante el uso de software. También subcontratamos el desarrollo de software.  UNO is an IT startup. We want to help make your business or idea even better by using software. We also outsource software development.' />
        <link rel='icon' href='https://uno.ooo/rec/img/favico.png'/>

        <link rel='canonical' href='uno.ooo' />
        <meta name='ROBOTS' content='INDEX,FOLLOW'>
        <!--Estilos-->
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/base.css'/>
        <!--JS-->
        <script src='js/base.js'></script>
    </head><body>
    <div class='hor-12 contenedor-general'>
        <div class='titulo'>
                <h2>i'm test1</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

***test2.php***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='es'
xmlns:fb='http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml'
xmlns:og='http://ogp.me/ns#'
prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
    <head>
        <!--Meta tags-->
        <title>UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú</title>
        <meta content='text/html' charset='utf-8' http-equiv='content-type'>
        <meta charset='UTF-8' name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1'/>
        <!--Open graph-->
        <meta property='og:type' content='website'/>
        <meta property='og:title' content='UNO - Creaciones Informáticas - Software en Perú'/>
        <meta property='og:image' content='https://uno.ooo/rec/img/carita_1000x500.png'/>
        <meta property='og:image:alt' content='Previsualizacíón de la imagen de presentación.'/>
        <meta property='og:image:width' content='1000'/>
        <meta property='og:image:height' content='500'/>
        <meta property='og:description' content='UNO es una empresa emergente de TI. Queremos ayudar a que su negocio o idea sea aún mejor mediante el uso de software. También subcontratamos el desarrollo de software.  UNO is an IT startup. We want to help make your business or idea even better by using software. We also outsource software development.'/>
        <meta property='og:url' content='uno.ooo'>
        <meta property='og:site_name' content='uno.ooo'>
        <meta property="og:locale" content="es_PE">
    </head>
```

Comment: Your `og:url` metatag, `<meta property='og:url' content='uno.ooo'>` isn’t the URL. Per [Facebook’s docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/getting-started/versioned-link/), you should be using `content='https://uno.ooo/test1.php'>` for your test1.php page. As for your *large* page problem, be sure your open graph data is at the top of the head section, before any large embedded style or script content — Facebook only requests the first 1MB of your page.

Comment: @RichDeBourke Thanks for the clarification on the `og:url` tag.   About the **large** page, as you can see, in the code I updated on the question, the page that gets `206` has the same code in the same position as the one with `404`. Is file length the problem?

Comment: @RichDeBourke , apparently it wasn't actually related to being close to the top, but some small mistakes in the html. In this case a double `xmlns:og` property in the `html` tag. Found thanks to your observation.